# Term for a body cast maker

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the word used for a person who makes body casts? Is compounder a good word?

Comment: You mean full-body orthopaedic casts? I doubt there is a word that specifically refers to makers of those. A _caster_ would be someone who makes casts in a more general sense, but a _body caster_ sounds very bizarre and would likely not be understood. A _compounder_ sounds like someone who makes compound words to me—I'd never guess it was anything to do with orthopaedic casts.

Comment: Yes I mean a full-body orthopaedic cast. A caster is fine. Isn't a compounder a guy who fixed bones without surgery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two relevant processes in the cast creation:

1. The creation of the unused materials
2. The application of the materials in order to form a cast

---

The people behind step (1) are probably referred to as mixers due to the creation process of [plaster of paris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaster_of_paris):

> When the dry plaster powder is mixed with water, it re-forms into gypsum. The setting of unmodified plaster starts about 10 minutes after mixing and is complete in about 45 minutes; but not fully set for 72 hours. If plaster or gypsum is heated above 392°F (200°C), anhydrite is formed, which will also re-form as gypsum if mixed with water.

Apparently, modern casts are often made from other materials but I will let you do futher research on your own.

---

Step (2) would most likely be performed by a doctor of some sort and is referred to as "setting" the cast:

> The **setting** of unmodified plaster starts about 10 minutes after mixing and is complete in about 45 minutes; however, the [cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthopedic_cast) is not fully dry for 72 hours.

The appropriate term "setter" would exist but it seems unlikely that anyone perform cast settings as their sole occupation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the person is usually called a **doctor**.  A type of doctor that would do this a lot would be an orthopedist.